# Adding Apache ACE target configuration files

Tags: bundle, configuration-files, target, apache-ace

Does anyone know how to put/load configuration files required for a target in Apache ACE other than configurator? I am using apache configurator to pick .cfg files from conf directry but i always get the error:
 
*ERROR* Unexpected problem providing configuration xxxxx to service [xxx, id=xx, bundle=xx/osgi-dp:xxx]

Does anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configurator bundle was designed to provide configuration via "cfg" files to the ACE server, relay and client. It was not designed for provisioning configuration data to a target. From your question, it looks like you are trying to do that, so...

For doing that, ACE supports the Auto Configuration Service as described in chapter 115 of the Compendium. In short, that specification uses configuration files in an XML format. These files, along with the resource processor, then get provisioned with the end result that the configuration data is sent to the Configuration Admin service automatically. More documentation about that process, and using "template" configuration files (in case you need to configure many targets with only a few differences between them) is described here:

http://ace.apache.org/user-doc/user-guide.html#using-the-template-engine-for-targets